# Magento 2 cart price rule Buy X get Y

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

In cart Price rule I need for example Buy X get y rule Means
I need to select for Buy X(specifice cetegory and SKU ) for get Y(specific cetegory and sku)

I need to select specific category and SKU for X products and specific category and SKU for Y products

How acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create Cart rule pelase follow below steps:

1. Login to admin.
2. go to Marketing -> Cart Price Rule
3. Now fill the basic information about your rule then in **Action** please select Buy x and get y rule.

You can choose this rule for specific category as well.

For more clear information you can use the below link of magento dev docs:
[Buy x Get Y](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html)

Hope this hepls to you.

cheers coding.

Comment: checked but i saw
Buy X quantity of product from category A, get Y quantity of the same product for free.
I need 
Buy X quantity of product from category A, get Y quantity of product from category B for free.
Is this possible ?

Comment: I don't think so you can select the product from same category but not from others. For this you might need use some other extension like Amasty one which will give you more control over your cart price rule.